# ¿Como creo un campo que permita funcionar como un Banner?

Tags: php, html5, bootstrap-3

Estoy realizando un formulario y me gustaría que se pueda agregar una imagen en uno de sus campos(Un banner, así como los de facebook o youtube), así como también la posibilidad de escribir sobre el o colocar una imagen sobre el mismo( A modo de título). Estoy usando PHP y las librerías Bootstrap 3 y jQuery, por lo que si estoy dispuesto a alguna sugerencia con esas librerías. Dejaré una imagen de lo que estoy diciendo, también incluiré el código que realicé pero que no me ha dado resultados, pero espero sea un poco orientador.
[image: Imagen de ejemplo]

Código:
https://jsfiddle.net/Xefiron/98owe5cr/3/

Answer (score 1):

Es interesante tu pregunta. Puedes combinar Jquery y/o hacerlo con Vanilla Javascript. Te dejo un ejemplo comentado de cómo se estaría comportando la imagen, si requieres enviar la imagen junto con los campos al PHP entonces tendrás que usar la funcionalidad nativa de HTML5 y la etiqueta `<form>`, si lo quieres asíncrono con AJAX entonces pásate por esta documentación [new FormData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

****Edito****
Ya te ahorré el trabajo de la funcionalidad de HTML5 y el form. Ahora solo cacha esas variables en el PHP y guardalas

```js
//Cuando el DOM esté listo
$( ()=> {
  
  //Creamos un listener que este pendiente cuando el input de tipo File cambie
  $(document).on('change','#theFile',function( e ){
    
    //Guardamos el objeto que es tipo BLOB
    var file =  e.target.files[0];
    //Creamos un objeto de tipo FileReader
    var reader = new FileReader();
    //creamos una URL temporal del archivo
    var urlTemp = reader.readAsDataURL( file );
     
     //Cuando la imagen termine de cargarse
    reader.onloadend = () => {
      //Asignamos el resultado a la imagen temporal (Retorna una imagen en Base64)
      var base64 = reader.result;
      $('#banner').attr('src', base64 );
    };
    
  })

});
```

```css
#banner {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
      <div class="bg-light p-3 mt-3 rounded border border-dark">
        <form action="tuphp.php" method="post">
        <img src="" alt="" id="banner">
        <input type="file" id="theFile" name="theFile" class="form-control form-control-sm">
        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" name="title" placeholder="Escribe un nuevo título">
        
        <label>Otro campo</label><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Otro campo" name="campo1">
        <label>Otro campo</label><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Otro campo" name="campo2">
        <label>Otro campo</label><br>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Otro campo" name="campo3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-1">Enviar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```